# How to iterate through dictionary in our preferred keys order in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
dct = {'first': 'pune', 'second': 'delhi', 'third': 'chennai', 'fourth' : 'bangalore'}
```

I want to iterate though this dictionary, but in my order of keys, I have an idea about this but I don't know how to implement it.

My idea:

```
my_key_order = ['second', 'third', 'first', 'forth']
```

Specify the order of keys in a list and use this `my_key_order` list for iterating through dictionary.

Don't know how to implement this.

Comment: You have a typo in the `my_key_order` -list. Forth should be fourth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try?

```
for k in my_key_order:
    print dct[k]
```

Only the first two keys:

```
for k in my_key_order[:2]:
    print dct[k]
```

Comment: I have not tried this, but i think this will work for me

Comment: And how to modify it if i want to take only first 2(or any no.
) keys of my_key_order ?

Comment: @Patrick have you read about [slicing lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)?

Comment: no, i don't know about slicing lists, but after your comment i understood it

Comment: why someone has decreased my reputation ?

Comment: @Patric this question has been downvoted by the SO community. If you read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), you might understand why.